# Why empty struct use no memory ? And why empty struct will use memory when it as a filed of a struct that has other fields?

Tags: go, memory, memory-management

I have two questions that make me confused.

1. Why empty struct use no memory? If `a := struct{}{}`, the variable `a` how to be stored in the stack.
2. When empty struct as a field of a struct, it will use memory?

[playgroud](https://go.dev/play/p/dqwuPshPL0c)

```golang
type EmptyStruct struct {
}

type st1 struct {
    a int64
}

type st2 struct {
    a int64
    b struct{}
}

type st3 struct {
    b struct{}
    a int64
}

func main() {
    const format string = "%-3s: size: %-2d, val: %v\n"

    es := EmptyStruct{}
    s1 := st1{}
    s2 := st2{}
    s3 := st3{}

    fmt.Printf(format, "es", unsafe.Sizeof(es), es)
    fmt.Printf(format, "s1", unsafe.Sizeof(s1), s1)

    fmt.Printf(format, "s2", unsafe.Sizeof(s2), s2)
    fmt.Printf("\t"+format, "s2.a", unsafe.Sizeof(s2.a), s2.a)
    fmt.Printf("\t"+format, "s2.b", unsafe.Sizeof(s2.b), s2.b)

    fmt.Printf(format, "s3", unsafe.Sizeof(s3), s3)
    fmt.Printf("\t"+format, "s3.a", unsafe.Sizeof(s3.a), s3.a)
    fmt.Printf("\t"+format, "s3.b", unsafe.Sizeof(s3.b), s3.b)
}
```

```
es : size: 0 , val: {}
s1 : size: 8 , val: {0}
s2 : size: 16, val: {0 {}}
        s2.a: size: 8 , val: 0
        s2.b: size: 0 , val: {}
s3 : size: 8 , val: {{} 0}
        s3.a: size: 8 , val: 0
        s3.b: size: 0 , val: {}
```

In the `s2`, the empty struct is the second field, all fields use 8+0 Byte, but s2 uses 16 Byte.

In the `s3`, the empty struct is the first field, all fields use 8+0 Byte, and s3 uses 8 Byte.

I guess the reason is memory alignment, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: probably an answer to the 2nd question:

I think is because the struct needs to point to somewhere that is not nil. the empty struct inside of `st2` is zero valued to an empty struct and it needs to ocupy some memory region so it doesn't point to a nil pointer. I don't know the reason of why that size for the `st2` empty struct and I don't know why the `st3` empty struct ocupy 0 bytes

Comment: And probably an answer to the 1st question: the empty struct that is not inside of another data structure ocupy 0 bytes because it doesn't have any field or property to point to. I guess the compiler assumes that variable is not going to point to any memory region so it doesn't need reserve memory for that variable and that variable practically useless

Comment: I think it is a bug (or an undefined case) of go compiler (it creates a memory aligment for an item which doesn't exist). Empty struct size seems to be 0 : https://go.dev/play/p/jl3OPcQW5rJ